# Why does Ubuntu opens the folder cointaining the file instead the file itself?

Tags: 13.04, nautilus, xdg-open

When I'm trying to open a file via search in the Ubuntu Dash or asking Chrome to open downloaded file, Nautilus opens a window containing this file instead of opening file in a related application.

System is Ubuntu 13.04. Inb4 I installed Nemo (as I am more familiar with it instead of ugly new Nautilus), but when switched back to Nautilus 3.4.2 with some patches.

Any help here? I guess there's something wrong with launch command in default applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, many thanks Braiam, I couldn't google any info in previous formulating. Deinstalling XFCE packages seems to solve the issue:

```
sudo aptitude purge exo-utils libexo-1-0 libexo-common libexo-helpers libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util6 libxfconf-0-2 xfce-keyboard-shortcuts xfconf
```